# Check if paperclip attachment has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

So in order to reduce duplication, I broke image attachments away from a Product model onto an Image model, so that similar products could share an image. Like so

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :imaged_items
    has_many :images, :through => :imaged_items
end

class ImagedItems < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :imaged_items
    has_many :products, :through => :imaged_items
end
```

What I would like to do is if I'm editing a product, I'd like to check whether the image has changed before I save it. If the image has changed, I don't want to update the existing record, I want to create a new one since the old image could be used by multiple Products.

Is there any way to do that? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO Through [Class: ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) ...You can use [changed](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/changed)

```
      person.changed # => []
      person.name = 'bob'
      person.changed # => ['name']

      ####OR ..other way as well         

      person.name = 'Bill'
      person.name_changed?  # => false
      person.name_change    # => nil
```

Comment: Is this in a before_save callback?

Comment: use it irrespective of the callbacks...as these method just check/track unsaved attributes of model.. @hobberwickey

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem in an `after_update` callback and I use `.dirty?` instead of `thumb_changed?`

```
after_update :foo, if: Proc.new{
    |model| model.title_changed? || model.summary_changed? || model.thumb.dirty?
}
```

Worked for me perfectly. Hope it helps